# Pasar datos desde activity a fragments

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de pasar un dato de una `Activity` a un `Fragment`, esto se debe pasar cuando presiono un botón. he probado con `Bundle` o directamente con get y se me pasa es un dato predefinido, pero al editar el campo de texto y unir el botón no se envía nada.
Ya probé por medio de: 'Bundles', 'Directos', 'Interfaces'.
Consta resaltar que el "Fragment" esta en un "Activity" diferente al otro "Activity".
¿Me podrian ayudar a tratar de solucionar esto?

Activity A:

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
//Esta es la Actividad principal, desde aqui se llama al fragment.
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView;
TextView txtIndice;
String Phone = "111-11-111-1";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    //Aqui uso el boton flotante para abrir una clase.
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Comentario.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Se llama el Fragment desde el Activity A:

```
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    android.app.FragmentManager fm1 = getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentManager fm2 = getFragmentManager();
    LinearLayout ly;
    LinearLayout ly2;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.pizza:
            ly = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.izquierda);
            ly.removeAllViews();
            fm1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.izquierda, new FragmentPizza()).commit();
            //FreagmentPedido es a donde debe llegar el texto de la ActivityB
            //Aqui invoco al fragmet
            ly2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.derecha);
            ly2.removeAllViews();
            fm2.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.derecha, new FragmentPedido()).commit();

            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
         } 
     return false; 
     }
 }
```

Activity B:

```
public class Comentario  extends AppCompatActivity  {
String datoFragment;
EditText comentario;
Button Enviar;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.comentario_flotante);
    comentario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Comen);
    Enviar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enviar_comentario);
    Enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

         }
     });
  }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class FragmentPedido extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

View myview;
Button test1;
TextView recibirComentario;
String recibeDato;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_pedido, container, false);
    test1 = (Button) myview.findViewById(R.id.pedir);
    recibirComentario = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.recibe_comentario);
    return myview;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    FragmentManager fm1 = getFragmentManager();
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.pedir:

        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

¡Hola! Dada la ausencia de código para más o menos visualizar el problema específico que tienes, describiré el método más simple para pasar datos entre componentes de tu aplicación utilizando `Bundle`.

En tu caso particular, deseas pasar información desde el campo de texto de una `Activity` (a través de un botón) a otra actividad que gestiona el `Fragment` donde deseas mostrar la información desde tu primera actividad.

Desde tu primera actividad (`ActivityA` en este ejemplo):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //...

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Una vez receptemos el evento, usaremos Bundle e Intent para pasar datos de una Activity a otra
            // Inicializas el Bundle
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            // Inicializas el Intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ActivityB.class);

            // Información del EditText
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            String texto = editText.getText().toString();

            // Agregas la información del EditText al Bundle
            bundle.putString("textFromActivityA", texto);
            // Agregas el Bundle al Intent e inicias ActivityB
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // ...

}
```

En la segunda actividad (`ActivityB` en este ejemplo), en el método `onCreate()`, debes utilizar la key "textFromActivityA" que definiste previamente sobre el `Bundle` entrante (lo obtienes del `Intent`) para poder obtener la `String` que requieres, y así usarla en otras partes de tu actividad. De este modo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ... 

    // Obtienes el Bundle del Intent
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    // Obtienes el texto
    String texto = bundle.getString("textFromActivityA");

    // Creamos un nuevo Bundle
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    // Colocamos el String
    args.putString("textFromActivityB", texto);

    // Supongamos que tu Fragment se llama TestFragment. Colocamos este nuevo Bundle como argumento en el fragmento.
    TestFragment newFragment = new TestFragment();
    newFragment.setArguments(args);

    //Una vez haz creado tu instancia de TestFragment y colocado el Bundle entre sus argumentos, usas el FragmentManager para iniciarla desde tu segunda actividad.
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer_id, newFragment); //donde fragmentContainer_id es el ID del FrameLayout donde tu Fragment está contenido.
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    // ...

}
```

Luego, en el método `onCreateView()` del `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Primero inflamos la vista del Fragment para que podamos acceder a los elementos propios del layout donde quisieras mostrar los datos que le llegan al Fragment.
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentLayout, container, false); //donde fragmentLayout es la referencia a tu archivo XML con el layout del Fragment.

    String texto = getArguments().getString("textFromActivityB");

    //...

    return v;
}
```

Suponiendo que has atado correctamente las referencias de tus elementos (en este caso tu `Button` y `EditText`), no deberías tener problemas.

Te recomiendo que revises este enlace que describe de forma más detallada el proceso de comunicación entre componentes: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html.

Comment: Probare esta, te aviso si me funciona, gracias.

Comment: Voy a editar mi respuesta, e incluir código para que puedas iniciar un ``Fragment`` apropiadamente desde el listener del botón.

Comment: Oh, disculpa, no había revisado las últimas ediciones de tu pregunta. Corrígeme si estoy mal, pero tienes Activity A, donde está el botón, y Activity B que contiene al Fragment donde quieres mostrar la información que te llega desde Activity A, ¿no?

Comment: Exacto, tengo un Activity A donde tengo el editText y el botón y el Activity B donde tengo el fragment con su textview.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para atender este requerimiento. Me avisas si funciona.

Comment: ya edite la pregunta con codigo, ya que las soluciones que me han dado no me funcionado me ha tirado errores.

Comment: No me funciono el código amigo.

Comment: Ok, tu lógica establecida es realmente más compleja y diferente. Por favor, no copies y pegues directamente estos pedazos de código que coloqué en mi respuesta, pues solo pretenden dar una idea de un simple caso de paso de información entre componentes utilizando Bundle.

Comment: Editaré acorde al requerimiento en breve. Mientras, podrías comenzar haciendo algo con el botón Enviar en tu Activity B. No estás pasando nada de información a los otros componentes a pesar de que es ahí donde se origina tu información.

Answer (score 1):

Si no quieres usar un `Bundle`, puedes acceder la `Activity` que contiene tu `Fragment`.

- Con `Fragment#getActivity()` puedes acceder la actividad que contiene tu fragmento.
- Si accedes la actividad en `Fragment#onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState)` puedes estar seguro que la creación de tu actividad ya he terminado.

Ejemplo en tu fragmento:

```
@Override
public onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState){
    String cadena = getActivity().mStringCadenaEnActivity;
    // ahora puedes trabajar con el dato leido de un campo de la actividad
}
```

Comment: ya lo probe de esta manera, al momento de presionar el boton no se guardaba el dato en el textView,

Comment: Parece que vas a tener de compartir más de tu código entonces. Lo que se necesita es 1) donde obtienes el dato que quieres traspasar, 2) como llegas a la actividad/fragmento donde quieres usar el dato, incluyendo el código donde creas actividades y fragmento.

Comment: Vale, en cuanto pueda público el codigo

Comment: Amigo, la solución no me funciono, edite la pregunta, agregándole el código para encontrar una solución mas fácil y rapido