# Error al pasar el codigo de una activity a un fragment (recyclerview)

Tags: android, recyclerview

Quiero pasar el codigo que tengo de una activity a unos tabs y me da error

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

me da fallo en la linea que esta dentro del onCreateView

```
rv = vista.findViewById( R.id.recycler );

rv.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( getActivity() ) );
```

Por donde pueden ir los tiros? que codigo puedo mostrar mas para que me puedan ayudar? no se si esto servira pero las importanciones de los fragmnets los hago con android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_VoteAct"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.lujan.confirmaciones.Views.FinalActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitulo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:maxLength="25"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/ColorActionBarTitle"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDescripcion"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:maxLength="70"
    android:text="@string/description"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCodigo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:onClick="shareCode"
    android:text="@string/code"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#00bcd4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_diasrestantes"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_contador"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:ignore="OnClick" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="102dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitulo"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnYes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:onClick="yes"
    android:text="@string/Yes"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="OnClick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:onClick="no"
    android:text="@string/No"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="OnClick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSoSo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:onClick="maybe"
    android:text="@string/Maybe"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="OnClick" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_contador"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/share_code"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_diasrestantes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnNo"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="301dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDescripcion"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv.calendar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/add_to_calendary"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt.calendar"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/agendas"
    android:onClick="calendario"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv.calendar"
    tools:ignore="OnClick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_DeleteEvent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ColorActionBarTitle"
    android:onClick="deleteEvent"
    android:text="@string/Delete_evento"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="OnClick" />
```

Codigo Fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View vista = inflater.inflate( R.layout.tab3_fragment, container, false );

   // loadLanguage();
   // setContentView( R.layout.activity_final );
   // return new FinalActivity(this);

    // UI
    layout = vista.findViewById( R.id.layout_VoteAct );
    mTitle = vista.findViewById( R.id.tvTitulo );
    mDescription = vista.findViewById( R.id.tvDescripcion );
    mCode = vista.findViewById( R.id.tvCodigo );
    mImage = vista.findViewById( R.id.imageView2 );
    Si = vista.findViewById( R.id.btnYes );
    No = vista.findViewById( R.id.btnNo );
    Nose = vista.findViewById( R.id.btnSoSo );
    Delete = vista.findViewById( R.id.btn_DeleteEvent );
    compartir = vista.findViewById( R.id.tv_contador );
    calendario = vista.findViewById( R.id.tv_calendar );
    calendar = vista.findViewById( R.id.bt_calendar );
    //prueba=findViewById( R.id.tv_prueba );
    rv = vista.findViewById( R.id.recycler );
    //cont=findViewById( R.id.tv_contador );
    dias = vista.findViewById( R.id.tv_diasrestantes );


    // Intent
    code = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("code");
    dataEventIntent = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("data");
    guri = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("uri");
    random = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("random");
   // Intent intent = getIntent();
    /*
    code = intent.getStringExtra( "code" );
    dataEventIntent=intent.getStringExtra( "data" );
    guri=intent.getStringExtra( "uri" );
    random=intent.getStringExtra( "random" );
    */

    // Habilitar el modo OffLine de la BBDD
    if (FirebaseApp.getApps( getActivity() ).isEmpty()) {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp( getActivity() );
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled( true );
    }

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child( "Events" ).child( code );

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Event event = dataSnapshot.getValue( Event.class );
            mTitle.setText( event.getTitle() );
            mDescription.setText( event.getDescription() );
            //  prueba.setText( event.getDateEvent() );
            dataEvent=event.getDateEvent();
            code=event.getCode();
            url=event.getFoto();
            mCode.setText(event.getCode());
            ano=event.getAno();
            mes=event.getMes();
            dia=event.getDia();
            countDate();//diferencia fechas
            url();//foto evento
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(final DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    } );

    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    //RecyclerView
    FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    usuarios=new ArrayList<>( );

    rv.setLayoutManager( new LinearLayoutManager( getActivity() ) );  //FALLO RV RECIBE NULL
    adapter=new Adapter( usuarios );
    rv.setAdapter( adapter );


    database.getReference("Events").child( code ).child( "Users" ).addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            usuarios.removeAll( usuarios );
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user=snapshot.getValue(User.class) ;
                usuarios.add( user );

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    } );//cada vez que se cambien datos se refresca


    countVote();

    return vista;
}
```

Comment: Puedes poner el código del xml que estas utlizando en el fragment por favor. saludos

Comment: @Serna puesto xml

Comment: que es lo que te da error exactamente? Lo que dice el error es que no esta inicializado el objeto
Objeto objet = new Objeto(); supongo que te faltara por algún lado https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67985/pasar-datos-desde-activity-a-fragments aqui tienes un ejemplo

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de tu fragment. Creo que el error esta en que inicializas tu recyclerView en el onCreateView en lugar del onViewCreated.

Comment: @Serna El recycler y el adapter lo he llegado a pasar antes de postear el error sin exito, no se si habria que pasar algo mas en el onCreateView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El layout  `tab3_fragment.xml` que inflas en tu `Fragment`,

```
 View vista = inflater.inflate( R.layout.tab3_fragment, container, false )
```

en realidad no contiene el `RecyclerView` con id `recycler` :

```
 rv = vista.findViewById( R.id.recycler );
```

incluso noto también que no contiene estos dos elementos:

```
  calendario = vista.findViewById( R.id.tv_calendar );
    calendar = vista.findViewById( R.id.bt_calendar );
```

Comment: El fallo mas tonto posible y todo por copy-paste y ganar tiempo, ya no me da el fallo y aunque el reciclerview no se ve es ya otra cosa, Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @lujan Creo que este error todos lo llegamos a tener aún teniendo algo de experiencia, saludos!